How to wait for user to press inline keyboard markup pyrogram
I want to wait for user to click one of the buttons in inline keyboard markup then execute the next lines based on the user click!
When I use callback query decorator, the message with inline keyboard markup is sent to the user then the rest of the code is executed.
I used pyromde to asking text based questions from user,
But for buttons I don't have any idea.

rest of code you have to run in callback function, not in current function

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
